# How can I change two dimensional grayscale image to one dimensional vector image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, grayscale

I have a grayscale image with size 28 by 28, and I plot it with plt.imshow(..., cmap='gray_r')
I'd like to plot the second figure, that has pixel number as a xlabel, and grayscale value as a ylabel.
But I don't know how to make it.
I tried it to make with imshow function after reshape a 2_d image vector to 1_d vector, but it gave me a simple black line that has no information.
And I don't have pytorch or tensorflow, so I'd like to make it with python module such as numpy, matplotlib.

[image]

Comment: "I tried it to make with imshow function after reshape a 2_d image vector to 1_d vector, but it gave me a simple black line that has no information" You should show this code. We can only tell you what is wrong with code that we actually see.

Answer (score 0):

```
# flat_image = 1_d vector
pixel_nums = range(28 * 28)
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(pixel_nums, flat_image)
```

This will plot the pixel numbers and their grayscale values in a scatterplot. More information can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).